# Oracle database startup problems

Tags: oracle

In Oracle, I have set the `log_archive_dest1='D:\app\administrator\orcl\archive'` parameter and shutdown the database. When I tried to start up the db, I got the following error:

```
SQL> startup mount;

ORA-16032: parameter LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 destination string cannot be translated

ORA-09291: sksachk: invalid device specified for archive destination

OSD-04018: Unable to access the specified directory or device.

O/S-Error: (OS 3) The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how I might fix this?

Comment: Not sure why this would be downvoted.  It's not as if there aren't enough SQL server questions around!

Answer (score 3):

You probably need a trailing \ on the dir name

ie D:\app\administrator\orcl\archive\

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Oracle but some things you might try are

- Make sure the permissions on the file path you're using allow the database to read / write to it?
- Make sure all the folders in the path already exist
- On Windows you might find the '\' characters confuse the database. Do you specify other paths in the same way for Oracle? An alternative may be to use '/' instead of '\'. Different programs that originated in the Unix world handle Windows paths in different ways